# Create an image from uploaded file

Tags: php, image-upload

I'm uploading files like so. (I can have multiple simultaneously upload, inputs will be added dynamically)

```
<form method="POST" action="ajax.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="uploadImage[]" id="file_input"> 
     <input type="file" name="uploadImage[]" id="file_input1"> 
     <input type="file" name="uploadImage[]" id="file_input2"> 
     <input type="submit" name="sendBtn" value="Click me">
</form>
```

Then I submit to my ajax where I need to create a `thumbnail` from the uploaded image(s) and upload both image and thumbnail.

This is the structure of my uploaded films, which I get from `$_FILES`.

```
Array
(
    [name] => array.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpKw4V3s
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 53038
)
```

How could I use functions like [imagepng()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagepng.php) with this structure?

I could easily do it with the fullPath of the image but I can't the client path with php.

Comment: why don't you do move_uploaded_file, then do image conversion  ?

Comment: If this is for anything but learn purposes, I would recommend to use some jQuery plugin like https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ for such things.

Comment: @zod Didn't think about it. So to be able to work with that uploaded file I would need to move it to a different place (not temporary) and then I could get the fullPath? If I write the file path static, its's working fine. My problem is making it work with that `tmp_name` instead the real full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use exiting libraries for suchs tasks, like https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ or http://image.intervention.io/

But from scratch, you would need to create an image resource first:

```
$src = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_img);
```

If you want to resize it for an avatar, you could do it like this:

```
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path_to_img);

  // COMPUTE NEW width and new height..
  // ..
  // creates black image of new size
  $final = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

  // set background to white
  $white = imagecolorallocate($final, 255, 255, 255);
  imagefill($final, 0, 0, $white);

  // copys and resized original image ($width,$height) into new image ($newWidth,$newHeight)
  imagecopyresampled($final, $src, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
```

To save it to a file or output would use

```
 imagepng($src, $path_to_new_file);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm already doing it. I just can't make it work with that structure. E.g using `$file['tmp_name']` instead of the full path.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro so `imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name'])` does not work?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro `imagepng` does need an image source, that is not the path `$file['tmp_name']`. You need to convert `$file['tmp_name']` into an image source with `imagecreatefrompng` and that is the first parameter of `imagepng`.